# Electron Tray blurs on mouseup

Tags: electron

[example focused tray icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vr9.png)

On my Mac, native menu bar icons have a semi-opaque background color when their app is focused. I'd like to achieve the same with an electron [Tray](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tray). However, this background color flashes on a click event. The background color appears onmousedown and disappears on mouseup. The order of events is:

mousedown - background color appears on tray icon

mouseup - background color disappears / app screen shows (the `BrowserWindow` instance)

mousedown - background color appears on tray icon

mouseup - background color disappears /  `BrowserWindow` instance hides

How can I persist the focused background color state while the `BrowserWindow` instance is active?

My hide / show strategy for the browser window is:

```
const { screen } = require('electron')

const toggleWindow = window => () => {
  if(window.isVisible()) {
    window.hide()
    return
  }
  const cursorPosition = screen.getCursorScreenPoint()
  window.setPosition(cursorPosition.x - 230,  0)
  window.show()
} 

const trayIcon = new Tray(iconPath)
trayIcon.on('click', toggleWindow(window))
```

where of course `window` is a `new BrowserWindow()`.

I tried [these two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193739/how-to-make-electron-tray-click-events-working-reliably), but they didn't help.

```
trayIcon.on('right-click',
```

```
trayIcon.setIgnoreDoubleClickEvents(true)
```

I've experienced this since electron v23; now on v28 with the same problem.